# Tabris.JS build fails after adding an icon in the Cordova config

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, tabris-js

So I created an [Tabris.JS](http://tabrisjs.com) app and everything worked fine until I tried to add an icon to the app.

I get the following errors when trying to build the android app:

```
:processDebugResources/home/travis/build/eclipsesource/tabris-js-build-template/build/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:27:23-37 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
 FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 2 mins 3.366 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/travis/build/eclipsesource/tabris-js-build-template/build/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/travis/build/eclipsesource/tabris-js-build-template/build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

(..)

/home/travis/build/eclipsesource/tabris-js-build-template/build/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:27:23-37 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/travis/build/eclipsesource/tabris-js-build-template/build/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/travis/build/eclipsesource/tabris-js-build-template/build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
 Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
travis_time:end:033db81c:start=1471880105396556780,finish=1471880238929469762,duration=133532912982

The command "grunt build deploy" exited with 6.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

This is the structure of the folder:

```
/cordova
    /config.xml
/res
    /icon.png
/package.json
```

There are of course other files, but they are not the problem.

config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="xx.xx.xx" version="0.1.0">
  <name>xxx xx</name>
  <description>
    xxx
  </description>
  <author email="xxx@xx.xx" href="https://xx.xx.xx">
    xxx
  </author>
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" version="1.1.1" />
   <platform name="android">
      <icon src="../res/icon.png" />
  </platform>
</widget>
```

I hope someone can help me fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had to add `drawable` in the name of the folder. I found this by trial and error.